# What's the point of defining Timer on MDB Message Driven Bean?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, message-driven-bean, ejb-timer

What's the point of defining Timer on MDB Message Driven Bean ?

Is it anyhow different from a timer on SLSB stateless sesstion bean or Singleton bean?

MDB are intended form message processing, why would I want to clutter them with timers? Slsb or singleton beans seems more appropriate place for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the use case is rare, but it might be that a message processing need to create an event to be fired at one time in the future.